# How to get the z values from a DEM?

Tags: dem

I have to get to know the approximate amount of volume of rocks in one area. For that, I need the elevation information to see where slopes or inclinations are located. 
I downloaded from the USGS Explorer the GMTED (Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data) and created a shapefile with the contour lines, where each line represent a particular elevation (I used this tutorial to do so: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html).

I then sent this information as a .dxf file to a person who wanted to calculate the volume with a program (he told me that it should be a dxf data). But when he opened the data, the elevation lines were just flat and the z values were missing. Does someone know what I have to do now? Is it even possible to get the z data from a DEM the way I did it? Where could I find it? I am just learning QGIS, so everything is pretty new to me. I use the version 2.12.3. –Lyon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ogr2ogr command line located under OSGeo4W Shell. To access OSGeo4W Shell go to Start in Windows --> programs --> OSGeo4W folder --> Click on OSGeo4W Shell, and write the following command:

`ogr2ogr -f DXF Path/to/DXF_File/Test.dxf Path/to/SHP_File/Test.shp -zfield NAME_OF_ELEVATION_FIELD`, where:

NAME_OF_ELEVATION_FIELD: it might be "ELEV" based on the tutorial that you followed.

To be clear, it will be like this:

`ogr2ogr -f DXF Path/to/DXF_File/Test.dxf Path/to/SHP_File/Test.shp -zfield ELEV`

[image]

After running the above command you will get 3D dxf file.

[image]

You check [here](http://gisforthought.com/gis-to-cad-using-ogr2ogr-part-1-shp-to-dxf-with-contour-data/) for more information.

If you do not have OSGeo4W folder in your program list, you probably downloaded the QGIS standalone file. So you can extend it by installing OSGeo from [here](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html), and select OSGew4W 32Bit or 64Bit depending on your system.

[image]

Comment: But this is in GIS? I use QGIS... and if not, could you explain me step by step where to write down the command? Sorry, but I am pretty lost right now... and thanks for your help!

Comment: @user69896 I edited my answer to include more information.

Comment: uff i tried to do it as you explained, but I got this error message: DXF layer does not support arbitrarz field creation, field 'ELEV' not created  What does it mean?

Comment: @user69896 I also received the same message, but when I checked the data it was OK, as you can see from the image above. Please check using CAD software to confirm.

Comment: ahh ok great, I will try it and tell you afterwards! Thanks so much

Comment: DXFs cannot contain attributes (kind of), so it does not create the "ELEV" attribute, it just uses it for the Z values of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial created a kml-file. How you translated it to dxf? When you want to have real z-values you have to create a 3d geometry. A column in a table is not the same.

One option ist to use the drape-function v.drape from grass-gis. It is availabe in qgis in the processing toolbox and creates a 3d geometry from a dem on a given vector (your contour lines). (well actually of course 2.5D , but i don´t want to confuse here... :) )

Comment: Well I stoped with the tutorial after creating the contour lines (that is a shapefile) and then I thought its ready to be a dxf file (sorry I still don't understand a lot of QGIS and geodata...). So what do I have to do exactly? and where can I find the tool?