# How to correctly convert a DEM/GeoTIFF to 3D Contours in a DXF file

Tags: dem, ogr2ogr, dxf, gdal-contour

I am trying my darndest to turn a DEM/GeoTIFF into a 3D DXF file of contours but so far haven't been able to make it work correctly - I still end up with a seemingly 2D DXF that I can open in DraftSight but "disappears" when I rotate it.

I'm doing this on MacOS Sonoma with GDAL and OGR tools installed via Homebrew.

### DEM Download

I am using the SRTM Downloader plugin in QGIS to download a NASA DEM file.

When I click "Set canvas extent" for the area I'm interested in I end up with the following coordinates:

- North: 36
- South: 35
- West: -106
- East: -105

When I click download it retrieves `n35w106.tif`

When I run `gdalinfo` on that file it tells me:

- CRS = WGS 84
- Unit = Metre
- ID: EPSG 4326

### Clipping the DEM

I use `gdalwarp` to clip the file to the portion I care about - I  want to avoid generating large files.

```bash
gdalwarp -overwrite -te -105.8043495 35.5711759 -105.7954624 35.5785203 ./input/n35w106.tif ./output/clipped.tif
```

This produces a 2KB file that opens just fine in QGIS.

I then use `gdal_calc.py` to convert the elevation values from meters to feet:

### Converting Meters to Feet

```bash
gdal_calc.py --overwrite -A ./output/clipped.tif --outfile=./output/clipped_feet.tif --calc="A*3.28084"
```

The file it produces is also 2KB and also opens just fine in QGIS. They look the same but, as expected, have different ranges/values.

### Generating Contours

I then use `gdal_counter` to generate 3D contour layers at various intervals. For example 100 feet:

```
gdal_contour -a elev -3d -nln contours_feet_100 -i 100.0 ./output/clipped_feet.tif ./output/contours_feet_100.gpkg
```

This produces a 106KB GeoPackage file that loads into QGIS without any issue. It contains 6 features with fid, ID and elev columns. The elev values look correct for the area.

When I run `ogrinfo` on the file it tells me:

```bash
> ogrinfo output/contours_feet_100.gpkg
INFO: Open of `output/contours_feet_100.gpkg'
      using driver `GPKG' successful.
1: contours_feet_100 (3D Line String)
```

### Converting Contours to DXF

I then try to use `ogr2ogr` to convert the Contours GeoPackage file into a DXF file:

```bash
ogr2ogr -f DXF output/contours_feet_100.dxf output/contours_feet_100.gpkg -zfield elev
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'ID' not created.
ERROR 1: DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, field 'elev' not created.
```

From what I've read those errors are actually just warnings.

In DraftSight, if I use the `IMPORTDXF` command, the Model view shows me nothing and the Layout1 view shows me my contours.

When I import the DXF into Blender (I enabled the AutoCAD DXF Importer) and try using "Frame Selected" on that object I don't see anything.

If I open the DXF in QGIS, it shows up correctly even though it complains about having no CRS. If I change the CRS for that layer to 4326 it doesn't change in appearance, that I can see.

I'm not sure why I don't end up with a 3D DXF or am able to see anything in Blender. Am I missing something? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Good question. Try outputting directly to DXF from GDAL_Contour using -f DXF arg.

Comment: @MichaelStimson If I do `gdal_contour -a elev -3d -nln contours_feet_100 -i 100.0 -f DXF ./output/clipped_feet.tif ./output/contours_feet_100.dxf` then I get a 0KB DXF

Comment: While this is an old answer, it may give you some solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/186443/63384

Comment: That's not good, perhaps try forcing ogr2ogr to go 3d with -dim XYZ arg.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Adding `-dim XYZ` or `-dim 3` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @ahmadhanb Pretty sure I'm using the same arguments for ogr2ogr as in that other answer.

Comment: Please upload the DXF

Comment: @Mike-EZUSoft- Here are the files in question: https://github.com/lostmapper/dem2dxf-troubleshooting

Comment: Your DXF (contours_feet_5.dxf tested) contains heights.

Comment: @Mike-EZUSoft- How did you confirm that? When I load it in AutoCAD or DraftSight I only see a flat set of lines and if I rotate them, they disappear.

Comment: "I only see a flat set of lines and if I rotate them, they disappear."
I think for your DXF you should use an EPSG in meters/feet and not in degrees.
DXF itself doesn't know EPSG but only "numbers" and the numbers in degrees are very small :-)

Comment: @Mike-EZUSoft- Thank you! I added a step to reproject from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:32113 and now see a 3D model in DraftSight!